# Change of basis in an Hamilton system

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis, hamilton-equations

I came across the System of equations 
$\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
  \frac{d}{dt}p &= - \omega^2q \\
  \frac{d}{dt}q &= p \\ p(0)&=p_0,q(0)=q_0
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}$ 
which is equivalent to the standard form  
$\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
  \frac{d}{dt}x(t) &= J^{-1}Ax(t) \\
  x(0)=x0
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}$ ,

where $$x=\begin{pmatrix}
p  \\
q  
\end{pmatrix} J^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}, A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \omega^2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Now let $S=\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{\omega} & 0\\
0 & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\omega}} 
\end{pmatrix}$, then $J^{-1}A$ gets transformed to $\tilde{A}=S^{-1}J^{-1}AS=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\omega \\
\omega & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ 
and the system of equations to
$\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
  \frac{d}{dt}\tilde{p} &= - \omega \tilde{q} \\
  \frac{d}{dt}\tilde{q} &=  \omega \tilde{p}
\\ \tilde{p}(0)&=\tilde{p}_0,\tilde{q}(0)=\tilde{q}_0
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}$

The solution is given by
$$\tilde{x}(t)=e^{t\tilde{A}}\tilde{x_0}=e^{S^{-1}J^{-1}AS}\tilde{x_0}=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\omega t) & -\sin(\omega t)\\
\sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t) 
\end{pmatrix}\tilde{x_0}$$
Then I have to conclude $$x(t)= \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\omega t) & - \omega \sin(\omega t)\\
- \omega^{-1} \cos(\omega t) & \sin(\omega t) 
\end{pmatrix}x_0$$
which I think is an easy linear algebra exercise which unfortunately I can't solve and since I don't know which theory is involved, I can't rely on google either.. It is not clear to me how one computes $(\tilde{p},\tilde{q})$ in the first place, consequently I don't see how to invert this transformation. I tried by "doing the opposite", i.e. computing $S\tilde{x}S^{-1}$ but this doesn't yield the correct result.
I'm not looking for the computations, hints on how to proceed are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your change of coordinates is $\tilde{x}(t) = S^{-1}x(t)$, because then we see
$$
\frac{d\tilde{x}}{dt} = S^{-1}\frac{dx}{dt} = S^{-1}J^{-1}Ax = \tilde{A}S^{-1}x = \tilde{A}\tilde{x}.
$$
You've computed $\tilde{x}(t)$ correctly from there. If we let
$$
K = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\omega t) & -\sin(\omega t)\\ \sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t)\end{bmatrix}
$$
then we see
$$
x(t) = S\tilde{x}(t) = SK\tilde{x}_0 = SKS^{-1}x_0.
$$
So because we have
$$
SKS^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\omega t) & -\omega\sin(\omega t)\\ \omega^{-1}\sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t)\end{bmatrix}, \text{ we have } x(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\omega t) & -\omega\sin(\omega t)\\ \omega^{-1}\sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t)\end{bmatrix}x_0
$$
or, in terms of coordinates,
$$
p(t) = p_0\cos(\omega t) - \omega q_0\sin(\omega t),$$
$$q(t) = q_0\cos(\omega t) + \omega^{-1}p_0\sin(\omega t).
$$
Hence there appears to be an error with your proposed solution. You can verify that this is the solution to your original system.

On your confusion about "how one computes $(\tilde{p}, \tilde{q})$ in the first place," I'm not sure what you mean. If you knew how to generate $S$ in the first place, then you ought to know that all you're doing is changing bases, hence the formula $\tilde{x} = S^{-1}x$. But if you mean that you don't know where $S$ came from, it arises from the attempt at "moving a copy of $\omega$" from the original $dp/dt$ equation to the $dq/dt$.

This is a kind of "symplectic scaling" which preserves the Hamiltonian structure of the equations. Basically, you need to scale $p$ by some factor $c$, but since there are only two coordinates being used, the only way to preserve the structure is to also scale $q$ by $1/c$. Play around with possible $c$ choices, and you'll arrive at your $S$ matrix.

Comment: It's weird because the exercise comes from an old exam and shouldn't include mistakes, but your solution makes fully sense to me. Thanks for being so detailed, it really helped me out